# Ride matching in Google Maps with Rails 3 for a carpooling system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

We want to search through carpools to find an optimal carpool whose route passes through the user's location. The data in the carpool is just the start and end points. Assuming the end point is a common end point for the user and the car pool creator, what would be the best way to determine an appropriate carpool for the user? We are using Rails 3. Both Google Maps API v2 and v3 are possible solutions.

Comment: I understand that Google Maps now has a rudimentary traffic-dependent routing. That means it can generate different routes for a single begin-end pair of points. You seem to assume the begin and end uniquely define the route.

Comment: @MSalters This is a good point you make here. I have been looking at RouteBoxer, it takes a polyline for a route generated by one particular Directions request. Any thoughts on this? It's not clear how to search using it though. Any one particular polyline should do ideally or is there a way to make the user decide an optimal route from a directions request and use that as the baseline?

Comment: you're thinking implemenation. I was just pointing out a flaw in the request here, since I can't judge how relevant it would be for you.

Comment: The idea is not to worry about who is passing through your pickup/drop  point. The idea is to find out who is within a radius of your pickup point. Carpool providers rarely pickup people while in transit, they rather pickup people who are close to their start point. I have just finished developing a prototype using our framework (mcruiseon.com). Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to know is the detour, both in time and distance. There's no simple way to determine this mathematically from just cooridnates. Luckily, it's trivial to do with a routeplanner. Just calculate both the time with and without waypoint.

If you have a very large set of carpoolers, it helps to start with the ones that are physically closest . Once you get a carpool with a detour of `N` kilometers, you know that you can exclude all other begin/end pairs where the begin-user-end distance in a straight line is at least `N` kilometers more than the best route from begin to end. This is the logic behind A*; start with what looks best geometrically so you quickly establish an upper bound and need not spend a lot of work on long detours.